# How to remove old, unused keyrings in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.?

Tags: apt, updates, repository, gnupg

I frequently receive error messages of the following type:

> gpg: keyblock resource `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/rwky-nodejs.gpg': resource limit

It seems apt-key available cannot handle so many keyrings. An issue which has been [addressed in apt 1.1](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=733028). Until 1.1. is rolled out, is there an automatised (i.e. not manually one by one) way to remove old, unused and no longer required keyrings in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`?